# Applications of Will in Condensed vs. in Core

Tags: skills, fate, fate-core, edition-comparison, fate-condensed

Some months ago, I noticed a difference between the Core and Condensed editions in the way the Will skill is described. **I would like to know whether this is an intentional change between editions (or 'editions' - whatever you call the subtle variations in the crunch between the books), or whether all the functions attributed to Will in Core are to still be attributed to it in Condensed; and, if it's the former, which Skill(s) should take over those functions.**

To be more specific, Core's description of Will includes the following:

> You can use Will to pit yourself against obstacles that require mental effort. Puzzles and riddles can fall under this category, as well as any mentally absorbing task, like deciphering a code. Use Will when it’s only a matter of time before you overcome the mental challenge, and Lore if it takes something more than brute mental force to get past it. Many of the obstacles that you go up against with Will might be made part of challenges, to reflect the effort involved.
>
> Contests of Will might reflect particularly challenging games, like chess, or competing in a hard set of exams. In settings where magic or psychic abilities are common, contests of Will are popular occurrences.

In contrast, Condensed's description of Will doesn't even hint at anything like that, instead portraying Will is a pretty much exclusively reactive, not proactive, Skill (in fact the only one in the list that is like that):

> Will: Mental fortitude, the ability to overcome temptation and to withstand trauma. Will stunts let you ignore mental consequences, withstand the mental agony of strange powers, and hold steady against enemies who provoke you. In addition, a high Will rating gives you more mental stress or consequence slots (page 12).

Answer (score 6):

According to [this May 26 tweet by Fred Hicks](https://twitter.com/fredhicks/status/1265279023594209281):

> Skills (or whatever you care to call your rated attributes) are a cosmetic feature and should not be taken as canon from any source including Core. You should be clear about and define your scope for each skill specific to the implementation you create.

Answer (score 1):

### The scenarios Core posits for Will aren't exactly proactive either.

I mean, okay, locking particle effects with an enemy mage and screaming "WIZARD BATTLE!" is pretty proactive, but that's an optional extra for extra settings.

What's everything else?

> "Perducci's transactions must have left a trail somewhere in this assayer's archive! INVESTIGUESQUE!"
>
> "Cool, it takes you eight hours, roll to not get bored."

> "He thinks he has every advantage, what with the ropes and chains and shark tank and two dozen goons pointing guns directly at me. But I know that *The Chessmaster* Perducci isn't going to turn down a friendly game of chess... **for all the serum**!"
>
> "That's really how you're spending your last Fate Point? Knock yourself out, I guess."
>
> "Haha! EN PASSESQUE!"
>
> "So you sit down with Perducci for like two hours of staring at a little board and a bunch of patterns made by little plastic guys. This is gonna be several rolls to not get bored."

In contrast to the scenarios you'd associate with rolling Contacts (to find contacts) or Fight (to fight) or Physique (to apply your strength), in the scenarios you roll Will the skill isn't directly associated with the things you're trying to do, as much as it is with the **obstacles** to the things it's **already assumed** you can do.

Comment: For a while I considered this answer not wrong, but not particularly helpful for solving the main question. But these days I'm returning to examining some considerations that are related/adjacent to this question - ones relating to both mental games and Will (for a campaign I'm signing up for), and I'm finding your observations useful for further analysis. Have a +1.